# Loop para fazer append de googlesearch para vários elementos de uma lista

Tags: python, lista, loop, append, google

Olá,
Tudo bom, comunidade?
Sou iniciante com Python e com programação no geral e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida.
Descrevendo bem brevemente o problema: eu estou usando o googlesearch para retornar as 3 primeiros links de cada elemento de uma lista. 
Estou tentando fazer isso através de um loop para que abranja todos os elementos.
PORÉM aparentemente o programa retorna apenas a pesquisa para o primeiro elemento.

O loop está retornando a primeira pesquisa 5 vezes. 5 no caso é o Len da lista Cities :(

Agradeço a ajuda desde já!

```
Cities = [cidade y, cidade x, cidade z, ...]

y = []
for x in range(len(Cities)):
    x = 0
    for j in search(Cities[x], stop=3, pause=2): 
        links =[]
        links = links[:] + [j]
        y.append(links)
    x = x + 1

print(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo o seu raciocínio:

```
from googlesearch import search

Cities = ['Londres', 'Berlim', 'Paris', 'Moscou', 'Viena']

y = []
for x in Cities:
    links = []
    for j in search(x, stop=3, pause=2):
        links.append(j)
    y.append(links)
print(y)
```

Melhorando a legibilidade do seu código:

```
from googlesearch import search

cidades = ['Londres', 'Berlim', 'Paris', 'Moscou', 'Viena']

saida = []
for cidade in cidades:
    links = []
    for link in search(cidade, stop=3, pause=2):
        links.append(link)
    saida.append(links)
print(saida)
```

Melhorando um pouco mais seu algoritmo:

```
from googlesearch import search

cidades = ['Londres', 'Berlim', 'Paris', 'Moscou', 'Viena']

saida = []
for cidade in cidades:
    saida.append(list(search(cidade, stop=3, pause=2)))
print(saida)
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
from googlesearch import search
cidades = ['Londres', 'Berlim', 'Paris', 'Moscou', 'Viena']
saida = [list(search(cidade, stop=3, pause=2)) for cidade in cidades]
print(saida)
```

Todos os códigos acima produzem a seguinte saída:

```
[
  [
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Londres',
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Londres',
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cidade_de_Londres'
  ],
  [
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlim',
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlim_Ocidental',
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distritos_de_Berlim'
  ],
  [
    'https://oglobo.globo.com/mundo/mesas-de-volta-as-calcadas-cafes-bares-restaurantes-reabrem-em-paris-24458503',
    'https://noticias.uol.com.br/ultimas-noticias/afp/2020/06/02/milhares-de-pessoas-protestam-em-paris-contra-a-violencia-policial-na-franca.htm',
    'https://www.em.com.br/app/noticia/internacional/2020/06/03/interna_internacional,1153282/manifestacao-contra-violencia-policial-termina-em-18-detidos-em-paris.shtml'
  ],
  [
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscou',
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscou#Hist%C3%B3ria',
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscou#Geografia'
  ],
  [
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viena',
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viena#Hist%C3%B3ria',
    'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viena#Geografia'
  ]
]
```